# How do I re render the entire React Pivot Table UI component when I change the selection in select tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table, pivottable.js

I am new to react js and I am trying to create a pivot table using React Pivot table. I want to be able to select a data set using a select drop down menu and update the state and re render the full table whenever there is a change in the drop down selection just like the jquery example shown here https://pivottable.js.org/examples/rcsvs.html

It works before I make any selections or changes to the Pivot Table. I am able to toggle between the 2 datasets and the state changes in the Pivot table. But when I select a pivot dimension and use the pivot table, after that point, changing the select menu does not help me change the pivot table's state. Please help.

Here's my code.

```
import React from 'react';
import PivotTableUI from 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI';
import 'react-pivottable/pivottable.css';
import TableRenderers from 'react-pivottable/TableRenderers';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import createPlotlyRenderers from 'react-pivottable/PlotlyRenderers';


// create Plotly renderers via dependency injection
const PlotlyRenderers = createPlotlyRenderers(Plot);



const data1 = [{'Country':'USA','Sales':45000}, 
{'Country':'USA','Sales':50000},{'Country':'CA','Sales':15000}]

const data2 = [{'Product':'Sofa','Sales':5000},{'Product':'Dinner 
Table','Sales':50000},{'Product':'Chair','Sales':15000}]

const dataDic = {'Region':data1,'Products':data2}



class App extends React.Component {


constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {selectedOption: 'Region'};
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({selectedOption: event.target.value});

}


handleSubmit(event) {
  alert('You have selected ' + this.state.selectedOption);
  event.preventDefault();
}


render() { 


    return <div>
              <select defaultValue="Region" onChange={(e)=>   
 this.handleChange(e)}>
                    <option  value="Region">Region</option>
                    <option value="Products">Products</option>
              </select>
              <br/>
              <br/>

              <PivotTableUI
                  data={dataDic[this.state.selectedOption]}
                  onChange={s => this.setState(s)}

           renderers={Object.assign({},TableRenderers)}//,PlotlyRenderers)}
                  {...this.state}
              />

            </div>;
     }
 }



export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I delete the data property from s

```
<PivotTableUI
  data = {[{}]}
  onChange={ s =>{ 
    delete s.data
    this.setState(s)
  }}
  {...this.state}
/>
```

This won't overwrite the data in the parent class and will be automatically rendered with updated data

Answer (score 1):

you should add

```js
 renderers={{ ...TableRenderers, ...PlotlyRenderers }}
                            {...state}
```

to your `PivotTableUI`, see the full example:

```js
import TableRenderers from 'react-pivottable/TableRenderers';
import PivotTableUI from 'react-pivottable/PivotTableUI';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import createPlotlyRenderers from 'react-pivottable/PlotlyRenderers';
import 'react-pivottable/pivottable.css';

const PlotlyRenderers = createPlotlyRenderers(Plot);


function DataExploration() {

    const { dashboardData: { data } } = useSelector((state) => state.dashboardData)
    
    const ExpComp = (props) => {
        const [state, setState] = useState(props);
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    {
                        <PivotTableUI
                            style={
                                {
                                    width: "100%",
                                    height: "100%"
                                }
                            }
                            onChange={(s) => setState(s)}
                            renderers={{ ...TableRenderers, ...PlotlyRenderers }}
                            {...state}
                        />

                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
    return (

        <ExpComp data={data} />
    )
}

From more details check the doc: https://github.com/plotly/react-pivottable
```

Answer (score 0):

[Working code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/731wjvp50)

There were two problems;

1. `s => this.setState(s)` in your PivotTable's onChange property. 
   This overrides root state with all the props of your PivotTable. 
   When your page initiated, container's (`Grid`) state only contains `selectedOption:"Region"` but after interacting with the PivotTable, container has receives all the props of the PivotTable. Screenshot: 
   [image: State of the Container after receiving props]
2. `{...this.state}` prop in `PivotTableUI` component, passes all keys as props in container's state including `data`.(As seen in the screenshot above). And this overrides `data` property, `data={dataDic[this.state.selectedOption]}` After this, changes to `selectedOption` state does not re-render `PivotTableUI`

Solution

1. Change `s => this.setState(s)` with `this.setState({ pivotTableUIConfig: s });`
2. Define a `pivotTableUIConfig` variable which does not include data property. (Used [ES7 Object Rest Operator to Omit](https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90) data property)

   // Picking all the properties except "data"
       const { data, ...pivotTableUIConfig } = this.state.pivotTableUIConfig;
3. Change `{...this.state}` with `{...pivotTableUIConfig}`

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem and found a simple fix. The problem is that `data` prop always gets overwritten by `{...state}`. Hence we can assign data to state before passing it to `PivotTableUI`. And the `data` prop is no longer needed.

```
const state = {...this.state};
state['data'] = dataDic[this.state.selectedOption];
return (
  <PivotTableUI
      onChange={s => this.setState(s)}
      {...state}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<PivotTableUI
  data={updatedViewRates}
   onChange={s => {
     delete s.data //Hack to prevent new data from being overwritten by old data
        setState(s)}
        }
        {...state}
/>
```